# How to bundle services and repository in ASP.NET Core 6?

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-core-6.0

I haved created a simple ASP.NET Core 6 mvc app. Then Here's my Program.cs

[image]

I would like to know if ever I have to many services and repositories, can I bundle service and repo and call it here?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 4):

Yes, to do so, you need to have a new class called for example AddRepositories or AddServices which will be looking something like that:

```
public static IServiceCollection AddRepositories(this IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddScoped<IClientRepository, ClientRepository>();
        services.AddScoped<IProductRepository, ProductRepository>();
        return services;
    }
```

then in Program.cs you need to attach that bundle by adding this line:

```
builder.Services.AddRepositories();
```